# Keep navigation element highlighted when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to use the following code to get my nav element to stay highlighted once clicked. My page will not reload, but will display all content on one page - show this should work. Do I have a problem with selectors? Or is something else wrong? It looks like it should be working to me...

**HTML:**

```
<div class="admin-main-area">
   <div class="admin-left-nav">
      <ul id="admin-left-links">
         <li><a class="link" href="#">Orders</a></li>
         <li><a class="link" href="#">Reports</a></li>
         <li><a class="link" href="#">Add Product</a></li>
         <li><a class="link" href="#">Update Products</a></li>
         <li><a class="link" href="#">Update Stock</a></li>
         <li><a class="link" href="#">Update Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div  class="admin-content-area">
      <p>this is some content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
$('a.link').click(function(){
    $('a.link').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.active {
    background-color: #f43333;
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it.. works for me

Comment: This is working fine for me in JSFiddle - JQuery 3.1.1. - https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/u51og4w3/

Comment: all you need lastet jQuery [ https://jsfiddle.net/cttagtnx/1/ ]

Comment: where did you define your js? maybe before that html code?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/, just in case...

Comment: Right...the award for idiot of the day goes toooooo... MEEEEE. Good shout guy's i missed the js definition from my document!!!! :( all working now!

Answer (score 1):

At the time you setup the click event handlers the links are not yet loaded in the DOM.

Try this (it will setup the handlers when the DOM is loaded):

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  $('a.link').click(function() {
    $('a.link').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

})
```

Of course, you will also need to include jQuery before the `<script>` snippet

Here's a working fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/nsjfe5g1/

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you need , but for my understandings you can simply do this with `css` `:focus` selector

```
a:focus {
  background-color: #f43333;
}
```

Try with demo https://jsfiddle.net/nsjfe5g1/2/

Comment: BUT this way, the active element will not keep active or focused after user click on some other element of the document!